# Ramanujan sum and Mobius inversion formula

Tags: number-theory

In an exercise i am given that $c_q(n) = \sum \limits_{1 \leq a \leq q , (a,q)=1} e^{\frac{2 \pi i a n}{q}} $ which is called Ramanujan sum and i need to prove that its equal to $\sum \limits_{d|(q,n)} d \mu(q/d)$, i want a simple number theory proof !

My approach:
\begin{align*}
c_q(n) = \sum \limits_{1 \leq a \leq q , (a,q)=1} e^{{2 \pi i a n}/{q}} &=\sum \limits_{1 \leq a \leq q } e^{{2 \pi i a n}/{q}} \sum \limits_{d|(a,q)} \mu(d) \\
&= \sum \limits_{d |q} \mu(d) \sum \limits_{ 1\leq a\leq q , d|a}  e^{{2 \pi i a n}/{q}}  =   \sum \limits_{d |q} \mu(d) \sum \limits_{ 1 \leq j \leq q/d}  e^{{2 \pi i j d n}/{q}}.
\end{align*}
But i don't know how to get from this to  the desired formula (i got stuck here).

Comment: Hint: on the right-hand side, the inner sum is a geometric series whose value is usually $0$.

Comment: @GregMartin true, but i still don't see the connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have it because the geometric sum over $j$ is equal to either $q / d$ when $n$ is divisible by $q / d$ or zero otherwise. So then your sum can be re-written as

$$\sum_{\substack{d | q \\ q / d | n}} \mu(d) (q / d)$$
Note that instead of summing over $d$ with $d | q$ you can sum instead over $q / d$ with $d | q$. Thus the above can be re-written as
$$\sum_{\substack{d | q \\ d | n}} \mu(q / d) d$$
and this gives the desired conclusion since $d | q$ and $d | n$ if and only if $d | (q,n)$.